# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Syntax error while trying to use devise-pundit sample application in RUBY ON RAILS

```
mysql> grant all privileges on rails-devise-pundit_development to 'pavuluri'@'localhost' identified by '';

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-devise-pundit_development to 'pavuluri'@'localhost' identified by ''' at line 1

Database Name : rails-devise-pundit_development(default).
```

Is using rails in database name not allowed? (Reserved word)

Suggestions please

Don't know if information is adequate.

Comment: Can you add the whole query or SQL statement that's causing the error?

Comment: @McAdam331 Sorry edited

Comment: Will you please post the sql

Comment: gvgvgvijayan As  tried rake db:migrate i got to know access denied. So trying to grant privileges for particular users.

Comment: Can you please put the database name in quotes like this \`rails-devise-pundit_development\`?

Comment: @spickermann tried that already but it gave me Similar error with extra {'} near syntax error line in above error.

Comment: What is the statement you are actually trying to execute though?

Comment: @McAdam331 Am trying to grant permission for particular user for that database to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `rails-devise-pundit_development`.* TO pavuluri@localhost  IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

or:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `rails-devise-pundit_development`.* TO pavuluri@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `rails-devise-pundit_development(default)`.* TO 'pavuluri'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY password
```